# ARM template error while deploying azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-function-app

**2021-01-04T11:03:16.0647360Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0659882Z ##[error]Details:

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0662124Z ##[error]InternalServerError: There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 78006c94-253a-4b3f-8407-0d7690a7ca5d

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0663958Z ##[error]InternalServerError: There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 78006c94-253a-4b3f-8407-0d7690a7ca5d

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0665674Z ##[error]InternalServerError: There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 78006c94-253a-4b3f-8407-0d7690a7ca5d 

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0667350Z ##[error]InternalServerError: There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 78006c94-253a-4b3f-8407-0d7690a7ca5d

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0669314Z ##[error]InternalServerError: There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 78006c94-253a-4b3f-8407-0d7690a7ca5d 

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0671142Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

2021-01-04T11:03:16.0672521Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.**

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "current_environment": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "instanceNo": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "current_app_name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "current_app_name_short": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue":"66"
        // "maxLength": 4
    },
    "functionName": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [
            "searchindex",
            "delta",
            "product",
            "catalog",
            "category"
        ]
    },
    "vnetName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue":"networking-001"
    },
    "existingVirtualNetworkResourceGroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "rg-networking-001"
    }


},
"functions": [],
"variables": {
    "commonprefix": "[concat(parameters('current_app_name'),'-',parameters('current_environment'),'-',parameters('instanceNo'))]",
    "commonprefix1":"[concat(parameters('current_app_name_short'),parameters('current_environment'),parameters('instanceNo'))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "name": "[concat('plan-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix'))]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "linux",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
            "name": "[concat('plan-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix'))]",
            "workerSize": "3",
            "workerSizeId": "3",
            "numberOfWorkers": "1",
            "reserved": true
        },
        "sku": {
            "Tier": "PremiumV2",
            "Name": "P1v2"
        },
        "copy": {
            "name": "appplancopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('functionName'))]"
        }

    },
    {
        "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "apiVersion": "2018-05-01-preview",
        "name": "[concat('appi-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix'))]",
        "kind": "web",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
            "Application_Type": "web",
            "RetentionInDays": 90,
            "publicNetworkAccessForIngestion": "enabled",
            "publicNetworkAccessForQuery": "enabled"
        },
        "copy": {
            "name": "componentcopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('functionName'))]"
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "name": "[concat('st',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],variables('commonprefix1'))]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "Storage",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "properties": {
            "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true
        },
        "copy": {
            "name": "storagecopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('functionName'))]"
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "name": "[concat('func-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix'))]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "kind": "functionapp,linux",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', concat('appi-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix')))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat('plan-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix')))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', concat('st',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],variables('commonprefix1')))]"

        ],
        "properties": {
            
            "name": "[concat('func-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix'))]",
            "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat('plan-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix')))]"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "type": "networkConfig",
                "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
                "name": "virtualNetwork",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', concat('func-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix')))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('existingVirtualNetworkResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'),concat('subnet-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix')))]"
                }
            }
        ],
        "copy": {
            "name": "apppservicecopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('functionName'))]"
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {}}
```

Comment: Validation completed without error, error while deploying, deployed location is westeurope

Comment: well, this looks like a retryable error, just try again later

Comment: i have tried more than 5 times

Comment: well, the keyword is "later". where did you get the template? from the official sources or did you create it yourself?

Comment: Hi @pappu.jerin, if Nancy answer is helpful, would you please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting), we could see multiple reasons for this type of error:

- The resource type you're trying to deploy isn't yet available in that region.
- Downtime of either the service you're deploying to in the region you're deploying to.
- Downtime of Azure DevOps itself.

You could switch the **region** and then try it again.

In addition, We could [create ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/quickstart-create-templates-use-the-portal) by using the Azure portal and then deploy azure function app via the template.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the same issue with your template. Please note that there is no `networkConfig` type and `subnetResourceId` properties in the template-[Microsoft.Web sites/virtualNetworkConnections 2019-08-01](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2019-08-01/sites/virtualnetworkconnections), you could change the type to `virtualNetworkConnections` and properties to `vnetResourceId` like this:

```
    {
        "type": "virtualNetworkConnections",
        "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
        "name": "virtualNetwork",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', concat('func-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix')))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "vnetResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('existingVirtualNetworkResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('vnetName'),concat('subnet-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix')))]"
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: i was trying to deploy function app Subnet connection as a child resources in ARM template the child resources does not support iteration that was the issue for me and your answer is correct. Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean "the child resources does not support iteration"? Have you looked at my validated sample? I used a list of existing subnets named `concat('subnet-',parameters('functionName')[copyIndex('')],'-',variables('commonprefix'))`, then it could create the function app and integrated with each subnet Iteratively.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources#iteration-for-a-child-resource